# How to determine the row index in ng-grid for tool tip display

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I am using a ng-grid on my cshtml page, its gridoption code in controller is as:

```
    $scope.myGridOptions = {
    dataSource: myGridFiles,
    sortable: true,
    filterable: {
        extra: false
    },
    scrollable: true,
    dataBound: function () {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        $pageData.isLoading = false;
    },
    columns: [
        {
            template: '<span class="icon-adjust center"><input type="checkbox" ng-click="selectFile(dataItem)" /></span>',
            width: 28
        },

       {
            template:  '<a class="js-mul-tooltip" title="Row Number:{{row.index+1}}"><i class="mul-icon-row"></i></a>',
            width: 28
        },

        {
            field: 'UploadedDate',
            title: $i18n.filerepo.dateUploaded,
            template: '<span class="center">#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(UploadedDate, "yyyy-MM-dd"), "dd-MMM-yy") #</span>',
            width: '14%',
            filterable: false
        },
        {
            field: 'UploadedBy',
            title: $i18n.filerepo.uploadedBy,
            width: '11%',
            filterable: false
        },

        {
            field: 'Notes',
            title: $i18n.filerepo.notes,
            template: '<span class="text-overflow" ng-attr-title="{{dataItem.Notes}}" ng-bind="dataItem.Notes"></span>',
            width: '25%',
            filterable: false
        },
        {
            field: 'DocumentKey',
            title: $i18n.filerepo.uniqueidentifier,
            width: '14%',
            filterable: false
        }
    ]
};
```

I want to show a tool-tip in the second columns for each row where i need to fetch the row index on which mouse currently hovers and show: Row Number:1,2,3,4.. and so on

How can I achieve this.Please help

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Isn't shown the firsts two columns?

Comment: In second column, where I need to show the tooltip as: Row Number 1(or 2 or 3..).The row number is not coming:                                                         {
            template:  '<a class="js-mul-tooltip" title="Row Number:{{row.index+1}}"><i class="mul-icon-row"></i></a>',
            width: 28
        }

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not `row.index` but `row.rowIndex` so you should change it with:

```
{
     template:  '<a class="js-mul-tooltip" title="Row Number:{{row.rowIndex+1}}"><i class="mul-icon-row"></i></a>',
     width: 28
},
```

Comment: using: row.rowIndex doesn't give any thing that's blank